# didReceiveMemoryWarning時のdebugに関して

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

アプリの改修で、実機デバッグ中に、コンソールにdidReceiveMemoryWarningが出てることに気付いたので、leaksでどこだろと思って調べてるのですが、一番重い領域を確保してるところのstackを見たいのですが、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> no stack trace available for this block ・・・

と表示され、何なのか確認が出来ないのですが、これは、どうしたら良いのでしょうか

このアプローチが正しいのかもちょっとわかってないのですが、メモリ警告(didreceivememorywarning)が出た際の対応は、leaksを使って、leakしてるとこ調べて、
潰していく。といった対応でよいのでしょうか

よろしくお願いいたします

Comment: [Instruments ユーザガイド](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/InstrumentsUserGuide.pdf)を参照してみましたか？多機能なのでなんでもできますが、それゆえ複雑なので、「どうすればいいのか？何が正しいアプローチなのか？」というような漠然とした質問には答え辛いと思います。

Comment: 失礼しました。了解です。ありがとうございます。